# Как следить за точкой на видео-потоке с помощью Python и OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

Подскажите, как с помощью Python и OpenCV поставить точку на изображении и следить за ней с помощью веб-камеры. Или, если можно, литературу, где можно про это почитать...

Comment: Вообще написано что привязки к пайтону у данной библиотеки еще нет.